# asp repeater template conditional validation javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, templates, repeater

I have an asp repeater which has some item information, an accept button, a cancel button and a reason for cancellation text box. I want the cancel button to validate that there is some text in the cancel (and if there isn't pop up a "you need to enter a reason"). I want the accept button to just submit the item on the page. This is my attempt, but the function does not want to find (bind) txtReason

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelAcceptOrReject">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="AcceptOrRejectRepeater" OnItemDataBound="AcceptOrRejectRepeater_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemDescription")%>'></asp:Label
                <asp:Label ID="lblReasonForCancelling" runat="server" Text="Reason for rejection"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtReason"></asp:TextBox>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function fnCheckforCancelReason() {
                        var pgng = document.getElementById('<%=txtReason.ClientID%>').value.trim();
                        if (pgnd == "") {
                            alert('The textbox should not be empty...');
                            document.getElementById(txtReason).focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
               </script>
               <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ItemID") %>' OnClientClick="javascript:return fnCheckforCancelReason()" OnClick="btnReject_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnAccept" runat="server" Text="Accept" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ItemID") %>' OnClick="btnAccept_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

but the function does not want to find (bind) txtReason and I cant set a break point (chronme or ie)

I want to be able to put a break point in to debug the fnCheckforCancelReason

Comment: Why you don't use ASP.NET validators? They work  at client- and server-side(if javascript is disabled).

Comment: Because I think they may get messy to implement vs a simple javascript function being passed six or more parameters as although the logic in the example is simple, Only three controls in the loop, ultimately it may depend in eight or nine controls

Answer (score 0):

typo on pgng:

```
var pgng = document.getElementById(...
if (pgnd == "") {
```

Comment: Does that solve the problem or is it just a side-issue?

Comment: I still seem to have a problem resolving the ID of txtReason inside the text/javascript

Comment: Try adding `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the textbox. then you don't have to use `<%=txtReason.ClientID%>`, you can just use the id 'as is'. see if that helps. quotes are also missing on the 'setfocus' line.

Comment: still not managed to resolve, but I am starting to suspect as quite a lot else is working with similar design approach, that its another typo somewhere... once I get it all working I'll document, thanks for help